# return to initial position when the mouse is no longer over it

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I have this 3d parallax effect when the mouse hovers over the card. But I don't know how to make it return to its original position when the mouse is no longer on it.

```js
let cardParallx = document.querySelector('.card-active');

cardParallx.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{
    let x =(window.innerWidth/2 - e.pageX)/30;
    let y =(window.innerHeight/2 - e.pageY)/30;
    cardParallx.style.transform =`rotateX(${-y}deg) rotateY(${-x}deg)`;
});
```

```html
<div class="card-active">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this to your **CSS**:

```
.card-active {
width: fit-content;
}
```

And this to your **JavaScript** to get when te user mouse is not on hover and change your image rotation to default:

```
cardParallx.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    let x =(window.innerWidth/2 - e.pageX)/30;
    let y =(window.innerHeight/2 - e.pageY)/30;
    cardParallx.style.transform =`rotateX(0) rotateY(0)`;
});
```

To get something like that:

```js
let cardParallx = document.querySelector('.card-active');

cardParallx.addEventListener('mousemove',(e)=>{
    let x =(window.innerWidth/2 - e.pageX)/30;
    let y =(window.innerHeight/2 - e.pageY)/30;
    cardParallx.style.transform =`rotateX(${-y}deg) rotateY(${-x}deg)`;
});

cardParallx.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    let x =(window.innerWidth/2 - e.pageX)/30;
    let y =(window.innerHeight/2 - e.pageY)/30;
    cardParallx.style.transform =`rotateX(0) rotateY(0)`;
});
```

```css
.card-active {
width: fit-content
}
```

```html
<div class="card-active">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
</div>
```